# I have two netcdf files , I want to use one netcdf file to clip another netcdf file

Tags: python-3.x, python-xarray, cdf

one netcdf file is three Coordinates: time,lon,lat , this file is wish to be cliped and this file is multiple time series.And another netcdf file is tow Coordinates:lon, lat.

I tied to create a new multiple time series netcdf ,but failed.

Comment: Welcome to SO. What do you mean by clipped? Do you just want to crop one file so that it has the same min/max longitude and latitude as the other file?

Comment: We’re eager to help, but need more information. Please check out the guide to [ask] and how to create a [mre]. At the very least, we’ll need to know how your data is structured (pasting the result of `print(ds)` into the question as a code block would be a great start) and we’ll need to see your code and where you’re stuck (more description or a full traceback in the case of errors). Thanks!